# Stop Windows from switching to local computer for "administrator"?

Tags: windows, active-directory

Modern versions of Windows seem to have a "feature" wherein, at the login screen of a domain-joined machine, if "administrator" is entered as the username, it automatically switches from the domain to the local accounts.  If you're trying to log in as "domain\administrator", you therefore always have to type in "domain", whereas this is not necessary for logging into any *other* domain account.

This is getting very annoying so I'm wondering if there is a way to disable this behaviour.  Ideally I'd like to set group policy to stop it on all systems.

Web searches came up dry apart from the occasional mention of this "feature" as an annoyance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never seen a way to disable this, but then it's never been that much of an irritaton to me. My genuine answer is to use proper, allocated administration accounts with real user names. Not only is it best practise, but it solves this issue instantly.

In my opinion, the `Administrator` domain admin account is there to get you started. After that, it should be disabled or given an extremely complicated password and left for emergencies only.

Comment: "given an extremely complicated password and left for emergencies only." - exactly.  And like Chris S alludes to below, there is no accountability in a large shop if everyone is using the Administrator (or any generic account)...everyone can point fingers.  Use specific accounts tied to people if you care to know who did what when crap breaks randomly.

Comment: Not a large operation at the moment but still a good habit to get into.. I give lesser admins separate accounts as it is.

Comment: @Kevin I tried not to sound too preachy because a shocking amount of places just use Administrator for *everything*, but it is the only real way forward.

Comment: I try to sound preachy because people don't listen to good advice... They only act if you beat them over the head with best practices, or when they get hacked. Usually the latter.

Comment: @ChrisS Fair points!

Answer (score 4):

1. Local Administrator should always be renamed. There's a GPO setting for this.

   - Optionally you can disable or even delete the local admin account via GPO/GPP too.
2. Nobody should ever be logging in with a generic Administrator account except for extreme emergencies. Nobody should even know the Domain Administrator password, two or more people should set it, write their portions on paper and seal it in an envelope.
3. You should either have:

   - Your own user account, who is also a domain administrator (not preferred)
   - A user account, ie kevin. And a domain administrator account ie kevin-admin (preferred).

Comment: +1 very good points too.  Both good answers but Dan not being as high rep, I figured to give him the mark.  Problem I have is that we've (somewhat unwisely) ended up with permissions all over which differentiate between lesser Administrator*s* and the master Administrato*r* and changing things all over is a hassle.  Good example where it's easy to ignore this sort of thing while the installation is small, and then when it gets bigger it's harder to fix it!